# How to add exogenous input to nnetTs function?

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series

I am trying to train an open loop NARX (nonlinear autoregressive network with exogenous input) in R with 3 input variables:
1) time series of temperature
2) time series of rainfall
3) groundwater level of the previous nn iteration
and the target values, which is the groundwater time series.

All I have found here so far is the hint to use the `nnetTs` function in the `tsDyn` package. However, if I understood this function correctly, there is no argument for exogenous input (in my case the temperature and the rainfall).
Also I don't know how to set up an open loop or a closed loop NARX.

How can I add this exogenous input to the `nnetTs` function? Or is there a different function, which has all this built in?

Answer (score 1):

So after couple of hours of searching for alternative packages I found the nnfor package from 2017 which has funtions for such purpose. Just have a look if you want to build a NARX.